# Is there a way to detect AI answers from ChatGPT and co?

Tags: discussion

What possible ways are there to roughly detect if an answer or question has been wrote by [ChatGPT](https://openai.com/blog/chatgpt) or other artificial intelligence (AI) applications?

Any advice is appreciated and will go nicely with the "[Should AI answers be banned?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10049/273733)" featured discussion where some support banning and some support flagging/allowing with declarations/notices etc.

Comment: related https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/384459/237989

Answer (score 6):

For a start, there are multiple ChatGPT detectors. From the [`politics.meta.se`](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6455/44533) on this topic, the website [AI-content-detector](https://sapling.ai/ai-content-detector) was provided that could scan text to see if it was produced via AI. Additionally, on another forum (who I cannot remember sadly), the website provided was named [GPT-2 Output Detector Demo](https://openai-openai-detector.hf.space/) that supports Q's (questions) or A's (answers) being copy and pasted into the provided box to determine the likelihood of the Q or A being produced by ChatGPT.

Additionally, if you are using Google Chrome and want to install the extension [`Tampermonkey`](https://www.tampermonkey.net/), then you can have a button at the bottom of every question or answer to have them evaluated for AI likelihood (using [@Simon Dispa](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/161015/simon-dispa) as an example as [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/683820/273733) was at the top of the feed):

[image]

where the `Detect OpenAI` button is present you can click on it to receive a score, in this case 38.4% which is reasonable as much of TeX code has already been published.

[image]

Further advice on this script is contained on the [Stack Apps site](https://stackapps.com/q/9611) but it may be helpful to you if you want an automatic script to determine whether or not to raise a moderator flag.

Comment: It might help to analyse text and code (and maybe comments) separately, text probably flags AI likelihood much more clearly.  Code especially the more likely give away I've seen seems to just be non-working answers, maybe changes to any MWE that don't contribute directly to the (supposed) answer (particularly if superfluous rather than best practise).

Comment: @DaiBowen that's a very good point, TeX code seems to raise the %age high. I do not think the Detect OpenAI can only filter with text and not code so the comments/resources in Werner's answer are probably best.

Comment: Tampermonkey is an extension that does exist for many (desktop) browsers and only provides an interface for userscripts, it doesn't magically provide that “Detect OpenAI” link. Maybe move the link to the userscript above your screenshot and remove the restriction to Chrome. It works for me on Firefox as well (and reports 52.48% on my own top answer :|).